# how can I get fields from a table using a model?

Tags: laravel

Example table:

book

`id|name`

book_users

`id|user_id|book_id|col_1|col_2`

book_product

`id|user_id|book_users_id|other_1|other_2`

Result:

For example, for user ID 1

1. book.name | book_users.col_1 | book_users.col_2
2. book.name | book_users.col_1 | book_users.col_2 | book_product.other_1 | book_product.other_2

help me pl.

Comment: You should read up the [documentation for relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships). Your question is very vague

Comment: table.book contains book names.

table.book_users contains selected books are user.

table.book_product. user request for selected books.

Comment: Just go through the tutorials on [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch) and actually learn something about Laravel before asking a question about it here.

Comment: Do you have eloquent models and relationships set up? Without knowing this your question is rather vague and we can't really help you.